# How to retrieve deleted records from MySQL

Tags: mysql, data-recovery

Is there any methods to retrieve deleted records from a mysql database?

Comment: Open up your backup. You do keep backups, right?

Comment: Have you committed? If not just do rollback.

Comment: Depends on what storage engine you're using.

Comment: There also seems to be this: http://mysqlbugs.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-undelete-rows-from-fixed-length.html, I haven't really looked at it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924823/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql

Comment: If it's hugely important, contact Oracle support and they may be able to help you recover parts of the data that has not been overwritten. Count on it costing a hefty sum though.

Comment: hope this will help u [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6924888/552116) backing data up is the best method. However, it maybe possible to extract the lost data partially depending on the situation or DB server used. For most part, you are out of luck if you don't have any backup.

Comment: Use mysqlbinlog `mysqlbinlog binary_log_file > query_log.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Deleted records are gone (or munged so badly you can't recover them). If you have autocommit turned on, the system commits each statement as you complete it (if you have auto commit turned off, then do a rollback NOW - phew, you're saved -- but you are running with autocommit, aren't you?).

One other approach is to reply the activity that created the missing records - can you do that? You can either re-run whatever programs did the updates, or replay them from a binary log (if you still have the binary log). That may not be possible, of course.

So you need to recover the data from somewhere - either a backup of your db (made using mysqldump) or of your file system (the data files of MyISAM tables are all simply structured and on the disk - recovering InnoDB tables are complicated by the shared use of ibdata files).

Comment: Never say never - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible way to retrieve deleted records (depending upon your situation). Please check here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72303235/2546381