# Is it possible to fetch the result from the deletion?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

If I delete several rows from database, is it possible to fetch the result about which rows have been successfully deleted, which rows are not deleted?
I'm using PHP + MySQl, PDO . Thanks

Comment: No, but you could change delete to select first, to get the row details, then run the delete.

Comment: Is it okay to copy them to a temporary table before deleting them?

Answer (score 4):

No. it's not possible but however you can use `mysqlbinlog` to generate  a sqlfile

***See here:*** [How to recover just deleted rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924823/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

What I can think about this is.

1. Take all the pk column values(may be ids) to be deleted from a table into a temp table.
2. THen run the delete query on the main table.
3. After delete just join the temp table with main table and check the count to know how many rows deleted and how many not.
4. If you want to know row by row then you can get it just by joinig the temp table with main table.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the criteria that you used to delete the rows to `SELECT` them first?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save the selected row's data from database then you can delete those rows.After deletion you can display which rows are deleted,and the specific row details