# How to recover data from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database

I accidentally deleted all data from my SQL table. How to recover it?
The table still exists, only the contents in the DB have been lost.
I was trying to delete "id" COLUMN from the table, but unfortunately all the content got deleted. I used this command `delete from covers where "id"`.

How to recover the data ?

Comment: Restore most recent backup. Otherwise data is kaput!

Comment: Your question is more related to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: duplicate : [/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924823/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

Comment: An important lesson was learned.

Answer (score 0):

## [MySql Data Recovery](http://www.percona.com/products/mysql-consulting/data-recovery)

1. Install the same version of mysql.
2. Remove mysql directory from data directory of the server and copy it from the crashed server. **This is the key element**
3. copy directory of database you want to recover into data directory of new server
4. start mysql.
5. switch to **mysql** database: `USE mysql;` and run `REPAIR TABLE <table name>` on every table.
6. Do the same with database you want to recover

tip: make sure the 2 directories have the same permissions like data directory

If you did not save `mysql` database (mysql directory in your old server's data dir, then you can try to:

1. create database with the same name as database you want to recover.
2. Then you can create each table (it would be good to use the same structure - you'd have bigger chance of recovery).
3. then stop mysql server and delete files from database directory and overwrite them with files from old server
4. start mysql and repair each table.