# How to recover a Mysql Database Tables

Tags: mysql

I had done a project for college which tends to store large amountof students & employee data.it was an web-application developed by using php&mysql. now my problem is that,in one of the Student tables all records were deleted on 3 days back,i'm unware of it.jst nw i checked my database table.no records in it. i'm unware of backup & restore options in mysql db.help me guys how to get my data back it consists nearly 3000 students admissions data.it was great help to me...

Comment: An application keeping valuable records without a mirror-database or backup? That was a risky move to begin with. I'm not sure how anyone can help to be honest. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924823/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql).

Comment: Next time make sure to make some backups, you can even create cron job for it to make it easier. And always back up in more than one place, at least one in local and one in cloud.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can undelete records.
The fact is InnoDB doesn't actually delete records, it marks them as "deleted". So if you noticed the accident before MySQL overwrote the deleted records it's possible to recover. Check ["UnDrop for InnoDB"](https://twindb.com/undrop-tool-for-innodb/) tool, it can undelete the records. When fetching records with c_parser you will need -D option.

For MyISAM tables it's harder to undelete records. First of all MyISAM will overwrite the beginning of the record. The deleted block header is longer than a data block header, but the remaining part of the record remains untouched. myisamchk tool will show deleted block offsets. Having that + C coding can get your records back.