# fetch/select deleted rows in the same transaction

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to "see" deleted rows in the same transaction before `commit` ?

I need to do this in a `TRIGGER AFTER DELETE` where I need to select the deleted rows which are deleted by a cascade constraint

## update

It does not sound like its possible.. So I want to edit my question a bit.. Is it possible / is there a fast way to collect row ID's in a `TRIGGER BEFORE DELETE` and "send" them to a `TRIGGER AFTER DELETE`?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924823/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql) may help you.

Comment: delete queries can't return anything. but you could have a "before delete" trigger copy the relevant records to a temp table, and then select from that.

Comment: AFAIK triggers don't work on CASCADE.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the trigger is not on the constraint :)

Comment: @clarkk - what he meant is that a trigger won't fire if the row was deleted by a constraint. It will fire only if you used a query that clearly states `DELETE FROM x WHERE y`.

Comment: My comment was for @MarcB - i guess, but i probably misunderstood him :-)

Comment: Have updated my question

Comment: I don't think you can "send" them, but store in a temp table, like Marc B suggested. But i wouldn't use temp tabels for data manipulating (see statement based replication), rather do it on application site.

Answer (score 0):

check this oracle docs if i understand clearly you need this..
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr002.htm

Comment: the db is mysql, not oracle (even if oracle owns mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your problem is, but maybe this info will help you.

In general I wouldn't recommend to grant delete permissions to anyone, accidental delete can have disastrous consequences. Instead of executing the delete rather mark the rows for deletion and just hide them on the front-end side. Then you can eventually delete them manually if necessary.

If you want to check what you are deleting before you do it you would have to prepare a script that instead of executing the `DELETE` prints the query first or shows the rows you are about to delete. Keep in might doing that might compromise your security. If you just want to see how much stuff you are about to delete you can `SELECT COUNT` first the items you want to delete and print something like: "you are about to permanently delete x items. Is that ok?"

If you need it for testing, to show you what was deleted etc., use [MySQL Server Logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html). They might be turned off by default, but it depends on your configuration (usually only error log is enabled by default). Then you could check the General Query Log but it only logs executed queries, so you will only see that someone executed `DELETE FROM x WHERE y=z` but you won't see the values that actually got deleted, only the executed query. Also keep in mind that general query log can grow really fast depending on your workflow, on the other hand gives you a great insight of what was the last thing a particular user did before he encountered an error etc.

Does any of this helps you? If you need more info on particular topic post a comment and I will edit accordingly.